# When and why I have to omit copulas (linking verbs) from a sentence sometimes?

Tags: linking-verbs

When I read the definition of the "verb" in [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/verb), that's what I found:

> ***Verb***: a **word used to** describe an action, state, or occurrence, and forming the main part of the predicate of a sentence, such as hear,
>   become, happen.

The way that intuitively I would write the same thing was:

> a **word** **that is** **used to** describe an action, state, or occurrence,
>   and forming the main part of the predicate of a sentence, such as
>   hear, become, happen.

Then my question is when and why we can or we should omit such copula ([linking verb](http://www.angrylearnerr.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/32.jpg)) from a sentence? (As a English learner who 'follows the book' and put always the linking verbs in such cases I don't have yet the privilege to economy verbs and say what necessary to say only without to be wordy, that's why I'm looking for a rule or something like that to make me closer to the native English speakers)

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary definitions, like headlines, captions, titles, and notices, often have a special grammar where short words, including the copula, are omitted.

You can read

> Verb: a word ...

as shorthand for

> A verb is a word ...

*Used to* is a different question: even if this were written as a full sentence, it could start

> A verb is a word used to ...

The entire clause "used to describe an action, state, or occurrence, and forming the main part of the predicate of a sentence, such as hear, become, happen." is one kind of [reduced relative clause](https://www.grammarwiz.com/reduced-relative-clauses.html). You're right that you could insert "that is", but you don't need to, even in literary prose, or in speech.

So the answer to your question:

- you can very often omit the sequence *that/which is/are/was/were* if what follows is a present or past participle (and sometimes in other cases)
- in headlines, titles, captions, lists, definitions, a copula that is the main verb of the sentence is often omitted.

Answer (score 0):

As a native English speaker, I would say "a word that is used to". "A word used to" is a bit formal. I believe that in "a word used to", "used" is also a linking verb and that is why the two sentences have equivalent meaning.